# Flipping raster with Python

Tags: python, raster, rotate

I am trying to calculate summary statistics for a raster file. I am encountering a problem when loading my raster into Python.

When I load the raster and I plot it, it is flipped 180 degrees. This means it is upside down.

When the raster is loaded into QGIS or ArcMap is properly displayed. How can I proceed?

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import rasterio
import gdal
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.transform import Affine
import networkx as nx
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx as ox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

os.getcwd()

path = "path_to_data"
gis = "path_to_vector"

raster = "path_to_raster**"

raster_yearly_path = [f for f in glob.glob(raster + '*ppty.tif', recursive=True)]  

raster_yearly = []

for raster in raster_yearly_path:
    local = rasterio.open(raster)
    raster_yearly.append(local)

ax = show(raster_yearly[0])
```

[image: Inverted raster]

I cannot move forward since the basins will not be in the proper extent. Please check the image below. I need to process more than 500 rasters. This is why I am using Python.

[image: Correc raster]

Comment: It's not clear how you could generate this outcome (code necessay), but how does the order of row processing impact summary statistics?

Comment: What do you mean when you plot it in Python?  Are you using some Python library to plot your raster?  If so, this library may not recognize the world file associated with your data.  It is this world file that is allowing a GIS to properly display your data.

Comment: I have added some comments and more information.

Comment: your raster is fine, you're just plotting it wrong. `pyplot.imshow(<array>, origin='lower')`

Answer (score 3):

This answer clarifies Paul H. comment.

For instance if you open your raster with rasterio:

```
dtm="path_to_your_raster"
with rio.open(dtm) as src:
    elevation = src.read(1)
```

And notice that is flipped around. You can simply plot it with the argument origin 'lower' to flip it back the right way:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 9))
ax.imshow(elevation, cmap="turbo", alpha=0.5, origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

The more complex question is why it is flipped around when plotted in the first place? Which unfortunately I cannot answer for the moment. But this issue as been reported [here](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/1683) and [here](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/2565).